# Jquery hightlight horizontal hidden sub menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, highlight

I'm posting my question here in order to have some help. I have a horizontal webpage with a fixed menu. On this menu, I have hidden submenu which belong to one item of the menu which is not hidden. For example, home item is visible and has a sub meny home2 hidden. I would like, when I'm in home2 item that home is hilighted. I tried something in Jquery but it doesn't work. Do you know what I'm doing wrong ?

**[Here my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jarod51/WXm55/)**

**My HTML :**

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul id="list">
    <li id="item1"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li id="item2" class="hide"><a href="#home2"></a></li>
    <li id="item3"><a href="#newsletter">Newsletter</a></li>
    <li id="item4"><a href="#directions">Directions</a></li>
    <li id="item5"><a href="#directions2">Directions2</a></li>
    <li id="item6"><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>
    <li id="item7"><a href="#actor">actor</a></li>
    <li id="item8" class="hide"><a href="#actor2"></a></li>
    <li id="item9" class="hide"><a href="#actor3"></a></li>
    <li id="item10"><a href="#market">market</a></li>
    <li id="item11" class="hide"><a href="#market2"></a></li>
    <li id="item12" class="hide"><a href="#market3"></a></li>
    <li id="item13"><a href="#calendar">calendar</a></li>
```

**my css :**

```
   #cssmenu li.active a {
    display: inline;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00b8fd;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu li.active2 a {
    display: inline;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00b8fd;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

My Jquery script :

```
$(function(){
if( $("#item2").hasClass('active' ))
{
  $("item1").addClass('active2');
}
if ( $('#item2').hasClass('') && $('item1').hasClass('active2' )) {
$('#item1').removeClass('active2');
}


    if($("item8").hasClass('active'))
    {
        $("item7").addClass('active2');
    }
if ( $('#item8').hasClass('') && $('item7').hasClass('active2' ) && $('item9').hasClass('') {
$('#item7').removeClass('active2');
}

});

$(function () {
        var 
            animation = function ( href ) {
                var 
                    name = "active",
                    element = $( "a[href='" + href + "']" );

                $( "html, body" ).stop().animate( {
                    scrollLeft: $( href ).offset().left
                }, 1200 );

                element.closest( "ul" ).find( "li" ).removeClass( name );
                element.parent().addClass( name );
            },
            menu = $( "#list" );

        animation( menu.find( "li" ).eq( 0 ).find( "> a" ).attr( "href" ) );

        $( "#cssmenu a" ).bind( "click", function( event ) {
            var target = $( this ).attr("href");

            animation( target );

            event.preventDefault();
        } );

        $( "#next, #prev" ).click( function ( event ) {
            var
                positionActiveClass = menu.find( "> li.active" ).index(),
                menuLength = menu.find( "> li" ).length - 1,
                buttonId = $( this ).attr( "id" );

            if ( buttonId === "next" ) {
                if ( positionActiveClass === ( menuLength ) ) {
                    newElementActiveClass = menu.find( "li" ).eq( 0 );
                    newPositionActiveClass = newElementActiveClass.find( "> a" ).attr( "href" );

                    animation( newPositionActiveClass );
                } else {
                    newElementActiveClass = menu.find( "li" ).eq( positionActiveClass + 1 );
                    newPositionActiveClass = newElementActiveClass.find( "> a" ).attr( "href" );

                    animation( newPositionActiveClass );
                }
            } else {
                if ( positionActiveClass === 0 ) {
                    newElementActiveClass = menu.find( "li" ).eq( menuLength );
                    newPositionActiveClass = newElementActiveClass.find( "> a" ).attr( "href" );

                    animation( newPositionActiveClass );
                } else {
                    newElementActiveClass = menu.find( "li" ).eq( positionActiveClass - 1 );
                    newPositionActiveClass = newElementActiveClass.find( "> a" ).attr( "href" );

                    animation( newPositionActiveClass );
                }
            }

            event.preventDefault();
        } );

    } );
```

Comment: "when I'm in home2 item that home is hilighted" - What do you mean by when i am 'in' home2 item? initially home to is hidden then how can you access it... can you explain more clearly..?

Comment: Hi Tj, thanks for your reply. Yes home2 is hidden because I want that the user thinks he is again in home. If you want, home2 is like a submenu of home but hidden.

Comment: actually, home2 is a continuity of the home page